# Cannot Control if JSON is Undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, spotify

I'm trying to create a site in which, through the Spotify Web API, I display the information of a certain element (Artist, Track, Album, etc ...).
I was trying to make a check on the url of the profile image of the Artist object as it is not said to be present, but when the console runs it gives me the error "Unexpected token }".
Could someone help me on why?
Below I leave the code:

```
function ricercaArtista() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var token = document.getElementById("token").innerHTML;
  var artist = document.getElementById("artista").value;
  artist = artist.replace(" ", "%20");
  console.log(artist);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      var result = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < response.artists.items.length; i++) {
        console.log(response.artists.items[i]);
        try {                 //from here start the control on the image
          result += '<div class="panel panel-primary style="background:url(' +
          response.tracks.items[i].album.images[1].url + '");"><div class="panel-body">' +
        } catch (error) {
          result += '<div class="panel panel-primary");"><div class="panel-body">' +
        }
        'name : ' + response.artists.items[i].name + '<br/>' +
        'popularity : ' + response.artists.items[i].popularity + '<br/>' +
        'type : ' + response.artists.items[i].type + '<br/>' +
        '<a href="' + response.artists.items[i].external_urls.spotify + '">' + 'Apri su Spotify' + '</a><br></div></div>';
      }
      alert
      document.getElementById("artists").innerHTML = result;
    }
  };
  xhr.open('GET', "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=" + artist + "&type=artist", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
  xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: `result += '<div class="panel panel-primary");"><div class="panel-body">' +`

Comment: Voting to close as *"Simple typographic error(s)"*. In the future, take some time to research the error, and note that the corresponding line number is printed beside the error (generally on the right side). I'd imagine, given the line number and a basic researched idea of what this error means, you'd have found this solution pretty quickly!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can not figure out where the error is, can you please take back the correct function entirely?

Comment: In both your `try` and your `catch` you have an extra `+` sign after the last bit of text you're adding to `result`.